# Beats per minute calculator

Tags: timer, microphone, music

Basically I want to create a BPM calculator on an ATMega1284.

So I have a mic hooked to the ADC already (with potentiometer). I can probably calculate the BPM by getting samples for a while and getting the avg Sound level. From there I can check for peaks by comparing to the avg sound level. If its 6db (twice the volume) its usually a peak/beat in music. But then we have 8th notes and other things messing up the BPM as they're faster. And also the music overall could get louder in chorus...

I just need a cheap way to get close enough and make it feel like I have the BPM down. Maybe just calculate the BPM for the first 4-8 secs then move on...

The calculator microcontroller can then transfer the BPM via UART to another microcontroller and from then on I can just transfer the volume intensity. The project is basically a light show.

Some thing's I need. I'm not sure how to see the time elapsed between calculations. In C++ in the computer I would just check the clock on the computer. How on AVR?

Comment: Accurate BPM detection is actually quite a knotty signal processing problem, you're best off doing pre-filtering in analogue before feeding it into your ADC, unless you want to burn a LOT of CPU cycles doing hard sums. I'd look at existing hardware & software implementations to see what you can learn, plenty of DJ equipment that tries to detect BPM with varying results. Winamp makes a stab of it for visualisations too, there may be some code in the wild.

Comment: Have you studied the wav file of a piece of music and applied various filters in something like audacity to see if you can find something that will remove the chaff? When you crack this pls let me know. I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 1):

To do any good, you will have to sample the audio at some set rate (usually at some thousands of samples per second.)  You can  find out how many samples per beat you have and calculate from that to get the beats per minute.
As others have said, though, this isn't really a job for a little ATMega.  To do the job with any kind of accuracy, you will need to do some pretty hefty signal processing - an 8 bit processor at 20MHz is not going to do it unless you are an absolute DSP genius who can find a new, unbelievably efficient algorithm and implement it on an 8 bit microprocessor instead of a DSP.

If accuracy isn't important, you could do as you planned (detecting peaks.) The number of samples between peaks can be used to calculate the BPM.
Say you are sampling the audio at 8000 samples per second, and you find the peaks are 4000 samples apart.  That would 2 peaks per second, or 120 beats per minute.

As you already know, though, the simple method of detecting peaks will get you a lot of false peaks.  You might be able to reject peaks that are too close together, but you should be prepared for the results to be pretty lousy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your [µC's](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8272-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega164A_PA-324A_PA-644A_PA-1284_P_summary.pdf) peripherals include a variety of counter/timers, at least one of which will no doubt support an ISR designed to determine the time between windowed ADC peaks reflecting the beat.

Comment: Yes, but that's only the most trivial part of the challenge.  The hard part is knowing what features to measure between.

Answer (score -1):

This will probably get moved as it's not EE specific.

That said, Arduino has a millis() function that will tell you millis since boot, and you'll probably need an FFT to figure out the rest.

Comment: I'm dealing with an ATmega not an Audruino.
And yes, I could've placed in the CS section but I decided on here because I, effectively, need to handle the clock to work and find the elapsed time between beats. I ask for a smart way to do this.

Comment: well, seeing how an arduino is built to work with an ATMega, you could just look at how they implement the millis() function.

Answer (score -7):

The best way would be to use a crystal oscillator connected to the ATmega, as this will give you the most reliable readings.

The way a crystal oscillator works(If you don't know) is by using the mechanical resonance of a vibrating quartz crystal to create an electrical signal with a very precise frequency, and you can then calculate time in from this frequency

If, however, you don't want to hook up extra stuff, then you could use the chorus of the song, as it repeats multiple times and is always the same. Though this is time consuming, harder and will require a lot of the song to already finish before you get a good time reading, which may or may not be a hindrance depending on your final goal... But I recommend the crystal oscillator!

Comment: Wish I could get that oscillator but I don't have the time...
I guess I'll just find a really (i mean really) cheap way of getting it to work... unreliable but at least it works

Comment: Another possibility, Is generating signals from the atmega, and measuring the frequency of those, however that would require a LOT of calibration... And I can't pertain to its reliability, just a random thought

Comment: This does not address the question asked in any meaningful way.  At best, a crystal oscillator would give you a stable timebase for other measurements, but that's the trivially easy part of what is overall an extremely hard problem.